# How to cut part of text beneath masked object in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, mask

I have a masked object above text. Now I want to cut the masked object so that I can use different colors for the divided paths in the text.
[image: m1]

When I try using path-division command, it is dividing the text with the original object used in masking  and not the masked object. This is what I was able to get . How to divide the text using this masked object (masked map)

[image: m2]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your visual end goal is here but in essence you'll need to do your masking as a final stage.  You may need to duplicate your map(?) element, use the copy to interact with the ABC and then reinstate the original map.
Please somehow let us know what you're trying to achieve visually and then I'm sure somebody will provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to:

1. Cut away portions of the map with a top shape using 'difference' (Ctrl+-). The resulting map should look like the one masked but is already sliced into sections.
2. Break the map apart (Shift+Ctrl+K) and group it to keep the parts together; then
3. Right click map group, enter group, select and color the sections as desired.

[image]